# Laravel (filament). how to add mask reactive text input

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Laravel (filament).  how to add mask reactive text input ?

> **this pattern does not work when input reactive**

```
TextInput::make('expire')
  ->reactive()
  ->required()
  ->length(5)
  ->mask(fn (Mask $mask) => $mask->pattern('00/00'))
  ->afterStateUpdated(function (Closure $set, Closure $get, $state) {
    //callToapi
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`

```
TextInput::make('expire')
  ->reactive()
  ->required()
  ->length(5)
  ->mask(fn (Mask $mask) => $mask->pattern('00/00'))
  ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) {
        $component->state(strtoupper($state));
  })
```

`